# C# - FluentNHibernate Mapping, How to map a non key column in a table with a generator

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I'm using Firebird DB and in NHibernate I've mapped my entity as mentioned below.
As `REQUIREMENTSHID` is a primary key I can easily map it to use a DB Generator's value i.e `"GEN_REQUIREMENTSH"`. I'm wondering is it possible to map a Non key column i.e `SequenceNumber` to get it's value from a generator, that would be `"GEN_REQUIREMENTSH_SEQNO"` ?

I'm new to NHibernate and .Net all together, need a little direction here how to use a DB generated value for a non key column.

```
public class RequirementHeaderMap : ClassMap<RequirementHeader>
{
    public RequirementHeaderMap()
    {
        Table("REQUIREMENTSH");

        Id(x => x.ID).Column("REQUIREMENTSHID").GeneratedBy.Sequence("GEN_REQUIREMENTSH");
        Map(x => x.SequenceNumber).Column("SEQUENCENO");
        Map(x => x.JobNumber).Column("JOBNO");
        Map(x => x.BatchesRequired);
        Map(x => x.Status);
        Map(x => x.Created).Column("CREATIONDATE");
        Map(x => x.Deleted);

        //... rest of the mappings

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is possible to achieve in the mappings but you could use a [NHibernate listener](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/events.html):

```
public class RequirementHeaderListener : IPostInsertEventListener
{
    public void OnPostInsert(PostInsertEvent e)
    {
        if (e.Entity is RequirementHeader header)
        {
            var number = e.Session.CreateSQLQuery("SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR Seq_Sequence").UniqueResult().ToString();
            header.SequenceNumber = int.Parse(number);
        }
    }

    public Task OnPostInsertAsync(PostInsertEvent e, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

This listener is called after any new object is added to the session.

You need to register this listener while creating the `SessionFactory`!